# javascript 3d with HTML controls

Tags: html, css, 3d, babylonjs

I would like to add 3d rendering to my line of business application.  There are a couple areas that could benefit from such an interface.

Is there a way to create a 3d box control and then layer regular HTML controls on it.  IE: Treat each side of the square like a separate form as if it was a tab control?

I would like to do much more than a simple box object but this seems like a necessary first step.

I've searched a great deal with no luck.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to put an HTML form on the side on a 3D cube while making it usable. You can use a static HTML page, rendered as a dynamic image, but you will lack the input capabilities, and won't be able to submit it.

But since you tagged your question with babylonjs, it seems like you looked in the right direction :-)

You can use Babylon's GUI to create your own form on top of a cube (or on top of any other 3D shape you want. You can find the documentation for the form controls here:

https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/gui#controls

After creating your form, add a submit button as well, and on clicking it, read the data stored in the form controls and submit your form.